# deserialization of pod struct stored in redis fails if key is defined as std::string

Tags: c++, hiredis

Storing of POD struct in redis works fine with `const char *` but doesn't if `std::string` is involved.

## const char * example

```
#include <hiredis/hiredis.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Test
{
  const uint32_t id;
  const char *name;
};
int main() {
  redisContext *context = redisConnect("127.0.0.1", 6379);
  if (context == NULL || context->err) {
      if (context) {
          printf("Error: %s\n", context->errstr);
      } else {
          printf("Can't allocate redis context\n");
      }
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  Test obj = {(uint32_t) 123, "foo bar"};

  const size_t size = 2 * sizeof(uint32_t) + (strlen(obj.name) + 1);

  cout << "object{id: " << obj.id << ", name:' " << obj.name << "'}; size: " << size << endl;

  redisReply *reply = 0;

  const char *key = strdup("some-key");
  reply = (redisReply *) redisCommand(context, "SET %b %b", key, strlen(key), &obj, size);

  if (!reply)
      return REDIS_ERR;

  freeReplyObject(reply);

  reply = (redisReply *) redisCommand(context, "GET %s", key);
  if (!reply)
      return REDIS_ERR;

  Test *res = (struct Test*) reply->str;
  cout << "result{id: " << res->id << ", name:' " << res->name << "'}; size: " << size << endl;

  freeReplyObject(reply);
  redisFree(context);
}
```

If I replace the lines:

```
  const char *key = strdup("some-key");
  reply = (redisReply *) redisCommand(context, "SET %b %b", key, strlen(key), &obj, size);
```

with

```
std::string key("some-key");
reply = (redisReply *) redisCommand(context, "SET %b %b", key.c_str(), key.size(), &obj, size);
```

the execution always ends in *Segmentation fault*.

I can't solve the issue by myself and I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: A struct containing a `std::string` is no longer a POD!

Comment: but the <code>struct</code> doesn't contain <code>std::string</code>. The key is <code>std::string</code> object.

Comment: You cannot render code like this in comments. Use backticks ``'

Comment: A POD structure is considered to consist of integral member types only. `std::string` isn't an integral type.

Comment: The bottom line is stop using `C` techniques on a C++ (non-POD) type.  There is a `std::is_pod<>` template function that you should start utilizing to ensure you're not producing programs that violate these restraints, or start writing C++ code and leave the `C`-isms behind.

Comment: thanks for `std::is_pod<>`advice, @PaulMcKenzie. With `static_assert(std::is_pod<Test>::value, "not a POD");` my example works fine. I'm afraid I don't understand first sentence in your comment. Could you explain it please.

Comment: @palik -- The issue is that there are types in C++ that are not going to work if you use `C` techniques on them, things like `memcpy`, `malloc`, `memset`, etc.  So if you're using those functions to manipulate non-POD types, your program will more than likely fail.  To ensure your program doesn't fail, the `std::is_pod<>` can be used to have your program fail to build at compile-time if a non-POD is used on code meant for POD types.  Having a failure at compile-time is a better option than a crash at run-time.

Comment: @palik For example, if you must have `Test` to be a POD type, then `std::is_pod<Test>` must return true.  Change `Test` to have a `std::string` member, and you will see your program will now fail to compile since `Test` is non-POD.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I got it:
replacement of second `redisCommand` statement

```
reply = (redisReply *) redisCommand(context, "GET %b", key.c_str(), key.size());
```

solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for comment. But could you explain what's wrong?

Comment: Why are you passing the address of the `key` type?  What is the purpose of that third argument?  If it's to do more "POD" stuff on that type, all you did was move the bug(s) to another function.

Comment: I [corrected](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41350104/revisions) my answer with address of the  `key`.